# Pushforward Filter

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, filters

While reading some notes I came across the notion of a pushforward pre-filter. If $g:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map of topological spaces and $F$ is a pre-filter on $X$, then then author claims that $g(F) = \{g(f) : f\in F\}$ is a pre-filter on $Y$. I am having trouble understanding why $g(F)$ must have the finite intersection property. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose given $g(f_1)$ and $g(f_2)$ in $g(F)$. You need to show that $g(f_1)\cap g(f_2)$ contains some element of the form $g(f)$, with $f\in F$. Since $F$ is a pre-filter, there is some $f\in F$ with $f\subseteq f_1\cap f_2$. It is immediate to show that for this $f$ it holds that $g(f)\subseteq g(f_1)\cap g(f_2)$. And this has nothing to do with topology.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the definition of pre-filters. In the notes, it says a pre-filter is a non-empty collection of sets closed under finite intersection. I interpreted this to mean that $g(f_1)\cap g(f_2) = g(f_3)$ for some $f_3$. It seems misleading to call this notion "closed."

Comment: there is some confusing variability in the definitions.